# How to declare an array of floats as a class variable in Objective-C when the dimension is undefined at the class instantiation time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In Java, it would look like this:

```
class Foo
{
  float[] array;
}

Foo instance = new Foo();
instance.array = new float[10];
```

Comment: That's not a class variable, that's an instance variable - one exists for each instance of the class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use a pointer:

```
float *array;
// Allocate 10 floats -- always remember to multiple by the object size
// when calling malloc
array = (float *)malloc(10 * sizeof(float));
...
// Deallocate array -- don't forget to do this when you're done with your object
free(array);
```

If you're using Objective-C++, you could instead do:

```
float *array;
array = new float[10];
...
delete [] array;
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way to do it. Create a NSMutableArray object and add NSNumber objects to it. It's up to you to decide whether or not this is sensible.

```
NSMutableArray *array;
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
[array release];
```

Comment: I guess there would be a performance penalty in not using the primitive float type.
Also, using a mutable array when the required dimension is known in advance (and is not going to change) seems to be overkill.

Comment: Yes, you would have to measure to be sure, but this would certainly be slower & use more memory. But in certain cases it could be handy to use NSArray/NSMutableArray. For example you can read & write to plist files easily with them.

Comment: You can initialize a mutable array with a specific size, even if that's known ahead of time you may still want a mutable array if you do not want to add all items to the array in one place.

There is a performance concern but generally it's much better than the danger of using malloc wrongly.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this in Objective-C is to use indexed instance variables:

```
@interface ArrayOfFloats : NSObject {
@private
  NSUInteger count;
  float      numbers[0];
}
+ (id)arrayOfFloats:(float *)numbers count:(NSUInteger)count;
- (float)floatAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)setFloat:(float)value atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@implementation ArrayOfFloats
+ (id)arrayOfFloats:(float *)numbers count:(NSUInteger)count {
    ArrayOfFloats *result = [NSAllocateObject([self class], count * sizeof(float), NULL) init];
    if (result) {
        result->count = count;
        memcpy(result->numbers, numbers, count * sizeof(float));
    }
    return result;
}
...
@end
```

For more see the documentation for [NSAllocateObject()](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIHCIIB). A limitation of indexed instance variables is that you can't subclass a class that uses them.

Comment: note: with ARC you can't use NSAllocateObject(), you need to stick with `+ (id)alloc`.