# Array Allocation in Objective C++

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to declare an array of numbers that is flexible in size in an obj C file

I am doing this:

```
long * arr = NULL;

a[0] = 0;
```

but this is giving bad_excess error

Can anyone help me out

also

```
long *arr = malloc(sizeof(long));
```

doesn't seem to help either

Comment: before you start commenting like a pro, you should do some homework Ishu...there is a language called objective C++ ..basically there are four languages C, C++, obj-C , obj-C++ ..if you have internet please make use of google before making outrageous comments on others and thinking your are the smartest..

Comment: Here you go Ishu : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html

Comment: The first try is meant to failed because you miss the allocation but what happens with the second try (malloc) ?  Where is the c++ there ?

Comment: @VdesmedT thanx for this info. Simon answer is also follow the obj-c concept

Comment: looks like Ishu spends more time trying to cry foul over what he perceives as frivolity than genuinely trying to solve others' problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this,

```
NSMutableArray *numArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This creates a array of objects. You can add any number of objects to it. Here you want to add long values. So use the following code,

```
[numArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:37];
[numArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:45];
[numArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:12];
```

NSMutableArray is flexible in size as you expected. You can add any number of objects.
If you want to get the number, you can do like the following,

```
long num1 = [[numArray objectAtIndex:0] longValue];
long num2 = [[numArray objectAtIndex:1] longValue];
```

You can also do as specified in the following link,

[How to declare an array of floats as a class variable in Objective-C when the dimension is undefined at the class instantiation time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405426/how-to-declare-an-array-of-floats-as-a-class-variable-in-objective-c-when-the-dim/405431#405431)

Comment: how can I directly typecast this NSMutableArray into a long array without looping?

Comment: Sorry man.. I don't have idea. I've edited my answer and posted a link. See if that link helps you.